# Reusing Quartus block schematic symbol file in another project

Tags: fpga, schematics, quartus, block-diagram

I am working on a Quartus project, requiring the usage of some designs previously created as block schematic design files in some other Quartus projects. I generated symbol files from the top design schematic using *File -> Create / Update -> Create Symbol Files for Current File...* and then copied the generated file into the new project, then added the component to the schematic design of the new project. Upon "Analysis and Synthesis", I encounter the following error:

> Error (12006): Node instance "inst" instantiates undefined entity "[name of the old project]"

And as a result, I can't find any way to reuse the component symbols generated in an old project, in a new one. Generated symbols from the *current* project work as expected, however.

How is it possible that I could reuse the old project's designs in the newer one?

*Note:* Both projects and design files are created with the exact same version of Quartus.

Comment: In Vivado, we pack the block design into IP and this packed IP folder is configured to use in the future projects. Quartus should have similar idea.

Comment: @MituRaj I personally haven't seen any similar option in Quartus... and searching in menus for a similar option didn't help me.

Answer (score 1):

In the **Project Navigator** of Quartus, right-click on **Files**, then click **Add/Remove Files in Project...**:

[image: Quartus Project Navigator Files]

This opens the **Settings** dialogue box.

Then click the **|...|** (ellipsis) button to browse for the BDF files you want to add:

[image: Quartus Settings Dialogue]

Comment: The problem is it is not only one design file to be added; in fact, the design file I wish to add, depends on a lot of other components defined in that same old project, and adding all those components alongside the main old design file to the new project will result in name conflicts in the new project... I was looking for a way to "package" the old design altogether to be able to use it in the new project.